# VkQueuePresentKHR throws a validation error

Tags: c++, c++17, vulkan

Obvious noob disclaimer here. I've been learning vulkan for a couple of days now and my `VkQueuePresentKHR` throws the following validation layer error.

```
VALIDATION LAYER : Images passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pImageIndices must be the index of a presentable image acquired from the swapchain specified by the corresponding element of the pSwapchains array, and the presented image subresource must be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR layout at the time the operation is executed on a VkDevice (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296)
```

My render pass creation is :

```
VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachmentDescription = {};
colorAttachmentDescription.format = this->surfaceFormat.format;
colorAttachmentDescription.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
colorAttachmentDescription.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
colorAttachmentDescription.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
colorAttachmentDescription.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachmentDescription.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachmentDescription.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
colorAttachmentDescription.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;


VkAttachmentReference attachmentReference = {};
attachmentReference.attachment = 0;
attachmentReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;


VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription = {};
subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &attachmentReference;
subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;


VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency = {};
subpassDependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
subpassDependency.dstSubpass = 0;
subpassDependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
subpassDependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;


VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo = {};
renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = &colorAttachmentDescription;
renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = &subpassDependency;


vkCreateRenderPass(logicalDevice, &renderPassCreateInfo, nullptr, &renderPass);
```

My code is at https://pastebin.com/bWZWFkD7

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to signal the semaphore by `vkQueueSubmit` before passing it to `vkQueuePresent`.

Comment: I know this is old but I'm having a similar problem. Isn't he doing so in lines 237, 243 already?

Comment: @tuket Perhaps the OP fixed it. It is why we generally require code in the question directly, so links do not die or change.

Comment: Ah, okay, I wasn't sure if I was missing something; I'm just learning Vulkan. Thanks for your reply :)